# How to implement cloth physics on whole animated mesh

Tags: animation, mesh, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to animate jelly-like creature
[image]
So let's say I have animated it moving/running/jumping and then I want **whole** body mesh to be like a jelly so it would follow original animated motion of the mesh

And here some specific questions:

- Maybe I have to extrude faces of mesh inside of it and assign them to pin group in physics tab?
- And if it so, is there any **other** way to do this?

P.S
Hope I've made myself clear(also sorry for my bad grammar) and if I really haven't - edits are always welcome

Comment: It sounds like Soft Body might be best to use in this situation. Can you edit your question to include more details - it would be useful to see pictures of your existing mesh and animated gif of your existing animation.

Comment: @RichSedman https://imgur.com/jws6nQw sorry, i have trouble uploading animation in the post, though i've managed to upload an image. hope that'll clarify my question

Comment: @RichSedman and unfortunately soft body physics is too slow, plus i've already did some jelly-like cloth sims(with pressure enabled) and i'm fine with it

Comment: The advantage of Soft Body is that the 'pin' (actually 'goal') is sprung - so that it's not absolutely positioned - but pins in cloth define actual position of that vertex. This means that for SB you do not need to add additional geometry to allow the 'wobble'. For cloth you'll be stuck with your proposed solution of adding internal geometry and animating that, allowing the 'jelly-like' cloth to move around it.